Android / Google Cast error codes - not defined
I'm adding the Google Cast SDK to my application. I am testing on nest home mini's, a pixel tab, and chromecasts. Occasionally, I get errors that are not defined in either com.google.android.gms.common.api's CommonStatusCodes or com.google.android.gms.cast's CastStatusCodes.
Examples: 2152 and 2055.
They seem to be intermittent, but it would be nice to know what exactly is going on.
applicable code:

    private val sessionManagerListener = object : SessionManagerListener<Session> {
        override fun onSessionStarted(session: Session, sessionId: String) {
            Timber.d("Cast session started with session ID: $sessionId")
        }

        override fun onSessionEnded(session: Session, error: Int) {
            Timber.d("Cast session ended with error code: $error (${getCastStatusCodeMessage(error)})")

        }
    }


    private fun getCastStatusCodeMessage(errorCode: Int): String {

        // Try to get the status code string from CastStatusCodes
        val castStatusMessage = CastStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(errorCode)
        if (!castStatusMessage.startsWith("unknown status code", ignoreCase = true) &&
            !castStatusMessage.startsWith("Unknown cast status code", ignoreCase = true)) {
            return castStatusMessage
        }

        // If not found in CastStatusCodes, try CommonStatusCodes
        val commonStatusMessage = CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(errorCode)
        if (!commonStatusMessage.startsWith("unknown status code", ignoreCase = true)) {
            return commonStatusMessage
        }

        // If still not found, return a default message
        return "UNKNOWN_CAST_ERROR_CODE: $errorCode"
    }

